# Why these code still use the lvalue function?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue, lvalue

I'm currently studying C++ lvalue and rvalue these days. I got a little confuse in below code.

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(){}
    explicit Test(int _i): i(_i) {}

    void doSomething()& {
        cout << "L value ref" << endl;
    }

    void doSomething()&& {
        cout << "R value ref" << endl;
    }
private:
    int i;
};
```

```
void callDoSomething(Test& t) {
    t.doSomething();
}
void callDoSomething(Test&& t) {
    t.doSomething();
}

int main() {
    auto a = Test();
    callDoSomething(a);
    callDoSomething(Test());
    return 0;
}
```

In above code, I will get this result:

```
L value ref
L value ref
```

I have check above code via debugger and pretty sure that in this code snippet: `callDoSomething(Test());` It will go to the rvalue reference one which is `callDoSomething(Test&& t)`. But why did it still call the lvalue member function?

I also tried template and still got same result.

```
template <typename T>
void callDoSomething(T &&t) {
    t.doSomething();
}
```

I have already read [this post](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) and knows that in template version. The `T &&t` is actually a universal reference. But after check via debugger. The type of `t` is still `Test&&` and we can get `Test&& &&t`. By reference collapsing's definition, we should still get `Test&& t`.

Can anyone explain why this happen? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for the post!. 'Its type is "rvalue reference to string", but it's an lvalue of that type."'. This make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The moment you have a variable with a name, it's an lvalue.
This means that `doAThing(X&& t)` takes an argument that's an rvalue; but in the function it's an lvalue called t.

If you were to do `std::move(t).doAThing()` you'll end up back with an rvalue call again.